# Exponential curve fit in python--parameters do not make sense

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, equation, exponential

I'm doing a curve fit in python using scipy.curve_fit, and the fit itself looks great, however the parameters that are generated don't make sense.

The equation is (ax)^b + cx, but with the params python finds a = -c and b = 1, so the whole equation just equals 0 for every value of x.

here is the plot and my code.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBfg7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBfg7.png)

```
# experimental data
xdata = cfu_u
ydata = OD_u

# x-values to plot for curve fit
min_cfu = 0.1
max_cfu = 9.1
x_vec = pow(10,np.arange(min_cfu,max_cfu,0.1))

# exponential function 
def func(x,a, b, c):
  return (a*x)**b + c*x 

# curve fit 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

# plot experimental data and fitted curve
plt.plot(x_vec, func(x_vec, *popt), label = 'curve fit',color='slateblue',linewidth = 2.2)
plt.plot(cfu_u,OD_u,'-',label = 'experimental data',marker='.',markersize=8,color='deepskyblue',linewidth = 1.4)
plt.legend(loc='upper left',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Y",fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel("X",fontsize=12)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 5)
plt.show()


print(popt)
[ 1.44930871e+03  1.00000000e+00 -1.44930871e+03]
```

How can I find the actual parameters?

edit: here is the actual experimental raw data I used: https://pastebin.com/CR2BCJji

Comment: Are you sure that xdata and ydata are both numpy array ? maybe you are giving list of data which in that case func return becomes wrong

Comment: @amirhm they are both numpy arrays

Comment: Can you joint to the question  your data (or a smal representative data) in clear text.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen function model is :

y(x)=(ax)^b+cx

In order to understand the difficulty encountered one have first to compare the behaviour of the function to the data on the range of the lowest values of X.

[image]

We see that y(x)=0 is an acceptable fitting for the points on a large range (at least 6 decades ) considering the scatter. They are the majority of the experimental points (18 points among 27). The function y(x)=0 is obtained from the function model only if b=1 leading to y(x)=(a+c)x and with a+c=0. At first sight python seems to give : b=1 and c=-a. But we have to look more carefully.

Of course the fonction y(x)=0 is not convenient for the 9 points at larger X.

This draw to think that the fitting of the whole set of points is an extension of the above fitting with values of the parameters different from b=1 and a+c=0 but not far in order to continue to have a good fitting on the above 18 points.

Conclusion : The actual values of the parameters found by python are certainly very close to b=1 and a close to 1.44930871e+03 and b close to -1.44930871e+03

The calculus inside python is certainly carried out with 16 or 18 digits. But the display is with 9 digits only. This is not sufficient to see that b might be different from 1 and that c might be different from -a. This suggests that the clue might be only a matter of display with enough digits.

Yes, the fitting by python looks great. This is a fine performance on the mathematical viewpoint. But the physical signifiance is doubtful with so many digits essential to the fitting on the whole range.